# Memory allocation and DOM elements

Tags: javascript, dom

While reading an MDN article about Memory Management (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management) I came upon the following question: Is it right to say that

```
var e = document.getElementById('div_id');
```

**allocates** a DOM element? I am using the same words with MDN article. In my opinion this is not right since the element-object with id="div_id" is already created in memory as part of the DOM tree. So var e, just references it and does not allocate new memory. Am I right or not?

Thank you

Comment: In future, please do not edit your question such that it invalidates existing answers. Strive to make your question accurate *before* you post it. If you do realise you need to alter your question *after* you've accrued answers, then post a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementById('div_id')` will not allocate memory for the element, as it already exists in the document tree.

However, the article you have linked doesn't actually say that memory would be allocated. So I don't see anything wrong with the article.

The only memory that gets allocated is for the variable `e` of the expression `var e = document.getElementById('div_id');`. This allocation happens in the stack. A new reference to the element is assigned to `e`, which consumes memory (even though it's a very small amount). No new memory allocation happens in the heap.

Comment: I am sorry. I meant document.getElementById not document.createElement. So, am I right to think that that object is already existing in memory?

Comment: @ILIAS I have edited my answer. Hopefully, this will make it clear for you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `document.createElement('div/any tag');` will create a **new node** and hence it has to allocate memory for it.

I guess, the memory management in the document is talking about particular case as explained below. Suppose you create a DOM element

```
var myDom = document.createElement('dom'); //or consider array of dom objects
//attach dom objects to document using appendChild/insertBefore apis

//on some **event** you remove dom nodes from the document using removeChild api
```

But at last, if you forget that the `myDom`/`array object` you used to store DOM nodes is not freed up, the DOM objects will still exists in the memory, even though they are not attached to the docuemnt.

So, if you think the DOM is not used any more, assign `myDom = null`, this will make GC to free the space.

> [Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management) : **Release when the memory is not needed anymore**
>
> Most of memory management issues come at this phase. The hardest task
>   here is to find when "the allocated memory is not needed any longer".
>   *It often requires for the developer to determine where in the program
>   such piece of memory is not needed anymore and free it.*